# Bert_Arch has no attribute predict error while loading pretrained model in Gradio

Tags: python, nlp, chatbot, bert-language-model, gradio

I am making a voice assistant for fast food restaurants. I have trained my model on Multi-Class Intent Classification on Distil-BERT and saved the file in pickle format in Jupyter. Now when I am loading it in my Gradio app to get intent from the trained model it is giving an attribute error.

I tried using the Trainer.predict method but it said there is no attribute like Trainer.
Here is Gradio code,

```
import gradio as gr
import pickle
import torch.nn as nn
class BERT_Arch(nn.Module):
   def __init__(self, bert):      
       super(BERT_Arch, self).__init__()
       self.bert = bert 
      
       # dropout layer
       self.dropout = nn.Dropout(0.2)
      
       # relu activation function
       self.relu =  nn.ReLU()
       # dense layer
       self.fc1 = nn.Linear(768,512)
       self.fc2 = nn.Linear(512,256)
       self.fc3 = nn.Linear(256,5)
       #softmax activation function
       self.softmax = nn.LogSoftmax(dim=1)
       #define the forward pass
   def forward(self, sent_id, mask):
      #pass the inputs to the model  
      cls_hs = self.bert(sent_id, attention_mask=mask)[0][:,0]
      
      x = self.fc1(cls_hs)
      x = self.relu(x)
      x = self.dropout(x)
      
      x = self.fc2(x)
      x = self.relu(x)
      x = self.dropout(x)
      # output layer
      x = self.fc3(x)
   
      # apply softmax activation
      x = self.softmax(x)
      return x

def make_prediction(text):
    with open("model.pickle", "rb") as f:
        clf = pickle.load(f)
    preds = clf.predict([text])  # Assuming your model accepts a single text input
    if preds == 1:
        return "Sure I will add your order, that will be $30, anything else?"
    elif preds == 2:
        return "I have added newer items in the list as well that will be $55."
    elif preds == 3:
        return "That's a great choice, you want in the veg or non-veg section?"
    elif preds == 4:
        return "Your order will be ready in 20 mins"
    elif preds == 5:
        return "Okay, I will make the quantity according to the specified number of people"

output = gr.Textbox()

app = gr.Interface(fn=make_prediction, inputs="text", outputs=output)
app.launch()
```

Here is the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\gradio\routes.py", line 516, in predict
    output = await route_utils.call_process_api(
  File "c:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\gradio\route_utils.py", line 219, in call_process_api
    output = await app.get_blocks().process_api(
  File "c:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\gradio\blocks.py", line 1437, in process_api
    result = await self.call_function(
  File "c:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\gradio\blocks.py", line 1109, in call_function
    prediction = await anyio.to_thread.run_sync(
  File "c:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\anyio\to_thread.py", line 33, in run_sync
    return await get_asynclib().run_sync_in_worker_thread(
  File "c:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\anyio\_backends\_asyncio.py", line 877, in run_sync_in_worker_thread
    return await future
  File "c:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\anyio\_backends\_asyncio.py", line 807, in run
    result = context.run(func, *args)
  File "c:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\gradio\utils.py", line 650, in wrapper
    response = f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_14968\3045401095.py", line 24, in make_prediction
    preds = clf.predict([text])  # Assuming your model accepts a single text input
  File "c:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1614, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError("'{}' object has no attribute '{}'".format(
AttributeError: 'BERT_Arch' object has no attribute 'predict'
```

Also I have added BERT_Arch class in my Gradio code because it was not able to find from saved pickle model.

Comment: In your `BERT_Arch` where is the `forward` function? How is the data flowing through your model?

Comment: @Ro.oT thank you so much for pointing that out.....I have added the function in the code. Getting the same error

Comment: The model is trained on multiclass classification task. The user input is taken as audio which in model is used to determine intent using tokenization to point out to main words and number is generated according to predicted class.

Comment: Instead of calling `clf.predict([text])`, try with `preds = clf([text])`.

Comment: @Ro.oT thanks that worked

Comment: @Ro.oT I am not sure if this right way to ask, please don't mind if it isn't. Please can you look into another chatbot related error I am facing https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77212165/chatbot-not-recognising-intent-for-different-responses